# space between editText and softkeyboard

Tags: android, xml

i have an activity with an editText field almost at the bottom. 
when i focus on that editText field the keyboard shows up and pushes my edittext field up.

when it stops there is no space between editText and my softkeyboard.

is it possible to add some margin?

this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/bg_yellow"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_field"
            android:inputType="text"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

position of editText field before keyboard shows up:
http://postimg.org/image/826fwy18z/

and an image when keyboard is show up, with no space between cursor and keyboard:
http://postimg.org/image/97qlfb4zx/

Comment: Jan, Can you upload a screenshot? I didn't understand the problem.

Comment: i have tried but doesnt have enough reputation points :( is there an other way?

Comment: already uploaded the images :)

Comment: did you find your answer? I have same problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) property of Activity in manifest file.

Use android:windowSoftInputMode=**"adjustResize"** in your case. You can check other properties as well.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Add margin to the bottom of the edit text field

```
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
```

Comment: I have tried that before, but it does not have any effect on the space.